# Organizing a csv file of multiple datasets into a list of Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file, containing results from a Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) simulation (a sample of my csv file is attached as a google drive link; file size: 226KB). In particular, the csv file has information (x, y and z coordinates and velocity in three directions, so a total of six columns) about multiple streamlines (number of streamlines may vary depending on the case). Information about streamlines are separated by two  empty rows (see the sample csv file). Streamlines have may have different number of rows.

I need to read this csv file, and organize its data into a list of Pandas datafreames, like:

```
streamlineList = [df_for_streamline_1, df_for_streamline_2, ...., df_for_streamline_N]
```

Can somebody help me a way to do this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GCSIOrlrXDWjlWMkEWMTE36Wv7wlYD5b/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should work for you.

```py
import csv

import pandas as pd


def main():
    file_name = 'track0_U.csv'

    # Ensure CSV has Header Values
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
        try:
            sniffer.has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
        except csv.Error:
            print('CSV File must have header row')
            return  # End Main

    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        # Create a CSV Reader
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # Extract Header Information for Data Frame
        header = next(csv_reader)
        # Initialise DataFrame Storage List
        stream_line_data_frames = []
        # Initialise the Stream Data List
        single_stream_data = []
        # Loop over each row (except header) in CSV
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row:  # Row Has Data
                single_stream_data.append(row)  # Add to Stream Data
            else:  # Empty Row Found
                # Data in the stream
                if single_stream_data:
                    # Convert Stream to DF and append to list
                    stream_line_data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame(single_stream_data, columns=header, dtype='float64'))
                    # Empty Stream Data
                    single_stream_data = []

        # Do whatever you want with stream_line_data_frames
        # Here I just print out each stream in it's own csv
        for i, stream in enumerate(stream_line_data_frames):
            stream.to_csv(f'stream_{i}.csv', encoding='UTF-8', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program first tests whether the csv file has headers. This is necessary for building the DataFrame with column names. You can remove this if that aspect is unimportant to your use case.

The program then goes row by row through the remaining csv rows and adds them temporarily to the list `single_stream_data`. When a blank row is found it tests if there is data in the `single_stream_data` list.

If it has data, it is converted into a DataFrame and appended to the `stream_line_data_frames` list.

If an empty row is encountered and `single_stream_data` is empty, we do nothing and continue to the next row.

Some Assumptions Were Made:

- The Last Stream ends with at least one empty row

  - This is true in the sample csv, but it is a requirement for the last dataFrame to end up in the `stream_line_data_frames` list.
- The Headers are the same for all streams
- All streams have the same number of columns
- Any number of empty rows indicates that a stream has ended.

  - You could add a counter if you expected empty rows within streams to ensure that there were exactly 2 empty rows in between streams.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't know why my values are strings after the dataframes are created, so I cannot do math operation on them. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added ```dtype='float64'``` to my declaration of the DataFrame (and updated my answer) to encourage the values from the CSV to come over as float64. Be aware that there will be some rounding, but you will be able to use them as numbers.

Comment: Thanks! one quick question: what should I do if I want to add only selected columns during the looping over the rows? Say I want to to read another csv file (within the same function) which has the same x, y and z datapoints, but the forth column is another variable (say pressure, p);to avoid redundancy, I want to read only the fourth column in this new file, and append its data as last column of existing data frames, so that final data frames would have 7 columns, x, y, z, U_0, U_1, U_2 (from the first csv file)and p (from the second csv file). Let me know if I have to post it as new Question

Comment: Yes, posting as it’s own question with a more concrete example would be best.

Comment: Ok thanks, I could resolve this myself, but I posted another similar question here:https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/92327/organizing-a-csv-file-of-multiple-datasets-into-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes